# Загрузка изображения при помощи FileChooser

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно загрузить изображение при помощи `FileChooser`.

Однако он загружает в `File`. Можно ли как-то сразу загрузить `Image`, или как-то преобразовать класс `File` в `Image`?

И, да, ещё нужно сделать так, чтобы при выборе файла отображались только изображения.

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Я новичок в Java.

---

Немного подумав я понял, что можно получить путь к файлу, и загрузить его:

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    String FileDis = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Main.stage).getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(FileDis);
    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(FileDis));
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Можно как-то избежать ошибки, или нужен другой способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать обертку над FileChooser например так:

```
package imagechooser;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageChooserDemo extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    ImageChooser chooser = new ImageChooser();

    chooser.setAvailableFormats("*.png", "*.gif", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg"); // Указываем форматы для FileChooser.


    Label placeHolder = new Label("Изображение не выбрано"); // Если изображение не выбрано, тогда показываем данный компонент.

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(); // Корневой контейнер, в него помещаются кнопка для выбора и само изображение.

    root.setCenter(placeHolder); // Так как изображение не выбрано отображаем текст 'Изображение не выбрано'

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(); // Данный компонент показывает выбранное изображение.

    Button button = new Button("Выбрать изображение"); // Кнопка для выбора изображения.

    BorderPane.setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER); // Выравнивание кнопки по середине.

    root.setTop(button); // Добавление кнопки в контейнер.

    button.setOnAction((event) -> { // Обработчик событий для нажатия кнопки.

      Image image = chooser.openImage(); // Выбираем изображение.

      if (image != null) { 

        imageView.setImage(image); // Установка изображения.

        imageView.setFitWidth(100.0); // Установка ширины в 100.0. 

        imageView.setFitHeight(100.0); // Установка высоты в 100.0.

        root.setCenter(imageView); // Добавление изображения в контейнер.

      }

      else

        root.setCenter(placeHolder); // Если изображение не выбрано, тогда показываем 'Изображение не выбрано'

    });


    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640.0, 480.0); // Создание сцены.

    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Установка сцены.

    primaryStage.setTitle("Демонстрация ImageChooser");

    primaryStage.show(); // Показываем окно.

  }

}


// Класс для выбора изображения.

  class ImageChooser {  

    private final FileChooser chooser;

    private final List<ExtensionFilter> filters; // Фильтры файлов по их расширениям.


    public ImageChooser() {

      chooser = new FileChooser();

      filters = chooser.getExtensionFilters();

    }

    // Метод для выбора изображения.
    public Image openImage() {

      File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(null); // Открываем файл.

      if (file != null) {

        URI uri = file.toURI(); // Преобразуем файл в URI.

        return new Image(uri.toString());

      }

      return null; // Если изображение не выбрано, тогда возвращаем null.

    }

    // Метод для утановки форматов.
    public void setAvailableFormats(String ... formats) {

      filters.clear(); // Удаляем все прошлые форматы.

      if (formats != null && formats.length > 0) { // Если есть что добавить.

        ExtensionFilter filter = 

          new ExtensionFilter(String.join(", ", formats), formats);

        filters.add(filter);

      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: всё хорошо но выдает ошибки :

на 66 строке "Cannot resolve symbol 'ExtensionFilter'"

на 75 строке "Incompatible types.
Required:
java.awt.List

Found:
javafx.collections.ObservableList
<javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter>"

на 101 строке "Cannot resolve symbol 'ExtensionFilter'"


и на 105 "Cannot resolve method 'add(ExtensionFilter)'"

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста в самый вверх файла(там где слова import), есть ли там запись java.awt.List? Ее там не должно быть.

Comment: Ошибка вероятно состоит в том что вы приводите тип javafx.collections.ObservableList к типу java.awt.List. Вместо java.awt.List должен быть импортирован java.util.List.

Comment: всё заработало большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Устами [ораклового сайта](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) глаголет истина:

```
BufferedImage img = null;

try 
{
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/ImageTest/pic2.jpg")); //Вот тут вместо new File вставляем свой, полученный из FileChooser
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: только теперь как получить из буфера картинку класса : "Image".

Comment: BufferedImage это подкласс Image. Можете использовать так или просто поменять определение переменной 'Image img = null;'

Answer (score 0):

вот вы итоги нарыл в инете вот этот метод вот если кому то надо

```
    public static javafx.scene.image.Image createImage(File file) throws IOException {
    java.awt.Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
    if (!(image instanceof RenderedImage)) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null),
                image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        image = bufferedImage;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "png", out);
    out.flush();
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    return new javafx.scene.image.Image(in);
}
```